# How to activate a specific profile, other than default one defined in settings.xml, in maven projects?

Tags: maven

I have two profiles (`gsi-repos` and `my-repos`) in my `settings.xml` file and `gsi-repos` is the default active profile.

How can I activate profile `my-repos` in some of my maven projects? Is this something that can be done in my project `pom.xml`?

**settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>gsi-repos</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>cp-releases</id>
                    <name>CP Releases</name>
                    <url>http://org.release-server.com/nexus/content/repositories/cp-releases</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>my-repos</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>my-releases</id>
                    <name>My Releases</name>
                    <url>http://my.release-server.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>gsi-repos</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: `mvn -Pprofile ...` but this looks wrong. Usually you should have only a single release repository...best is having in nexus a public group configured and not different repositories.

Comment: Do you release via a CI server (Jenkins, TeamCity, Bamboo)? So you could create different settings.xml files and choose which one to use depending on the build. Another approach would be to configure the release urls as properties and the projects will use the property right for them in their distributionManagement section.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I agree that one should have a single release repository. The reason I am using two different release repositories is that one is my m company's and other one is my personal repo which I use to release my personal projects. I have also installed Nexus repo manager, which is different from my company's Nexus repo manager, on my other Windows machine for that specifically. I do not want to publish and release my personal projects into my company's repository.

Comment: @wemu - No, I do not use a CI server. Can you provide some code snippet an how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to use profiles for this could be:

If you want to distinguish where releases end up in your nexus you can offer different properties in you settings.xml file. These properties would only need to be set on you CI server or on those machines that actually execute a `mvn deploy`

settings.xml:

```
[...]
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>nexus-profile</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
  <properties>
    <repo.releases.url>https://nexus/content/repositories/releases/</repo.releases.url>
    <repo.snapshots.url>https://nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</repo.snapshots.url>
    <repo.lib-releases.url>https://nexus/content/repositories/libs/</repo.lib-releases.url>
  </properties>
 </profile>
```

[...]

So in your pom.xml (or a matching parent pom):

```
  [...]
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Managed Release Candidate Repository</name>
        <url>${repo.releases.url}</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Managed Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>${repo.snapshots.url}</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  [...]
```

A project that would deploy its artifacts into the libs repository would only use a different property for the url.

You can put this into a projet-parent.pom and a libs-parent.pom - so any pom that uses one of them as its parent will not have to deal with distributionManagement at all.

The distributionManagement could be added into profiles and activate them depending on some activation (for example if a certain file exists): http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
But I recommend to not overuse profiles in maven.